# I'm using a VEctor2 to do a dash move but it won'tmove the character

Tags: c#

I created a script to make the character dash to the left or to the right but no matter what I do the character won't get pushed horizontally, when I switch it so that the character is pushed upwards the vector does work.
at the vectors there are two different ways of using methods because i tried both to see if either would work but they didn't.
here's the script.

```
public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
public float inputHorizontal;
public Rigidbody2D rb;

public float checkRadius;
bool isGrounded;
public Transform groundCheck;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;

public float dashSpeed;
public float dashTimeValue;
private float dashTime;

int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;

private bool facingRight = true;


void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    dashTime = dashTimeValue;
}

void Update()
{
    if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }
    
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, jumpForce);
        extraJumps = extraJumps - 1;
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
    if(dashTime == dashTimeValue && facingRight == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed, 1f);
        Debug.Log("eh");
        dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }else if(dashTime == dashTimeValue && facingRight == false)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashSpeed;
        Debug.Log("eh");
        dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    dashTime = dashTimeValue;
    }
    
    }
void FixedUpdate()
{
    inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(inputHorizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    if(facingRight == false && inputHorizontal > 0){
        Flip();
    }else if(facingRight == true && inputHorizontal < 0){
        Flip();
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

Comment: Which implementation of Vector2 are you using? The default [.NET Vector2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Numerics_Vector2__ctor_System_Single_System_Single_) does not have the static property `left`

Comment: I think it's the default one, I'm using it with Unity and visual studio code,